# Huffman coding c++

Tags: c++

So I am working on Huffman coding for a project. However, my code just doesn't work. When i ran it on visual studio, it didn't give me an error. What I was trying to do is to read a file and put all of them into a string. And get the frequency for each character in that string. But I think when the file got a little bit large, it seems like my code is running in a infinite loop. Can anyone explain anything to me? By the way, I had a sorted function that I used to sort a vector of node* by their frequency.

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open(filename);
string q;
string line;
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    q += line;
}
char y;
int count = 0;
int check = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < q.size(); i++) //if the string gets big, it seems to become an infinite loop in here
{
    y = q[i];
    for (int x = i - 1; x > 0; x--)  //make sure not counting the same char
    {
        if (y == q[x])
        {
            check++;
        }
    }
    if (check == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < q.size(); i++)
        {
            if (q[i] == y)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        node*x = new node;
        x->char1 = y;   //my node have char 
        x->freq = count; //my node has frequency
        list1.push_back(x);
    }
    count = 0;
    check = 0;
}
sort(list1.begin(), list1.end(), sorter);  //sort them from small to big
while (list1.size() > 1)
{
    node*left = list1[0];
    node*right = list1[1];
    list1.erase(list1.begin(), list1.begin() + 2);
    double sum = left->freq + right->freq;
    node* x = new node;
    x->freq = sum;
    x->left = left;
    x->right = right;
    list1.push_back(x);
    sort(list1.begin(), list1.end(), sorter);
}
list1.clear();
return true;
```

The following is my sort function

```
static struct {
bool operator()(NodeInterface* a, NodeInterface* b) {
    if (a->getFrequency() == b->getFrequency()) {//if the frequencies are even,
        if (b->getCharacter() == '\0') return false;
        if (a->getCharacter() != '\0') {
            return (int)a->getCharacter() < (int)b->getCharacter();

        }
        return false;
    }
    return a->getFrequency() < b->getFrequency();
}
```

} sorter;

Comment: The `sorter` looks wrong; if `a->getFrequency()` and `b->getFrequency()` are equal and both `a->getCharacter()` and `b->getCharacter()` are `\0`, both `a < b` and `b < a` are `false`. This will confuse the sort, and `return (int)a->getCharacter() < (int)b->getCharacter();` should be sufficient without the guards.

Comment: @KenY-N If `a` and `b` are equivalent, then both `a<b` and `b<a` should return false.

Comment: Something is overflowing, try changing the variables so they can store more data, ex. int64_t

Comment: The infinite loop problem would be easy to figure out, just use F10 to step through your code line by line! and check the variables values!

Comment: @aschepler Ah... Not enough coffee, or some excuse like that!

Comment: @KenY-N The problem is always the lack of coffee and pizza

Answer (score 1):

I see two major problems.

You have a for loop inside a for loop both initializing and using `int i`

Change the variable name of the inner loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < q.size(); i++) //if the string gets big, it seems to become an infinite loop in here
.
.
    if (check == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < q.size(); i++) //Change this to int j for example
        {
        .
        .
```

And the Sorter struct. I would rewrite it as this.

```
static struct {
    bool operator()(NodeInterface* a, NodeInterface* b) {
        if (a->getFrequency() == b->getFrequency()) {//if the frequencies are even,
            if (b->getCharacter() == '\0') return false;
            if (a->getCharacter() == '\0') return true;
            return (int)a->getCharacter() < (int)b->getCharacter();
        }
        return a->getFrequency() < b->getFrequency();
    }
} sorter;
```

A few suggestions for your for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < q.size(); i++) //if the string gets big, it seems to become an infinite loop in here
{
    y = q[i];
    //You can avoid this entire loop by using a structure like map
    for (int x = i - 1; x > 0; x--)  //make sure not counting the same char
    {
        if (y == q[x])
        {
        check++;
        //break; //if you use a loop, break it once you find the character.
        }
    }
    if (check == 0)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < q.size(); j++)//Renamed variable + you can start this loop from j = i as you know there is no occurrence of y before that.
        {
            if (q[i] == y)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        node*x = new node;
        x->char1 = y;   //my node have char 
        x->freq = count; //my node has frequency
        list1.push_back(x);
    }
    count = 0;
    check = 0;
}
```